# Python asyncio ошибка TypeError: run_in_executor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'executor'

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, asyncio, асинхронность

Пытаюсь использовать asyncio для выполнения одной из функций параллельно:

```
async def _Publish(newslettertext, towhom):
    users_ = await connect.getSpecificUsers(options={'status': 'retail'})
    print(users_) # я получаю необходимый результат на отлично!
```

И есть функция, которая запускает функцию которая выше:

```
async def test():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_in_executor(func=await _Publish(data['newslettertext'], towhom=pressedINFO))
```

После запуска я получаю результат с функции `_Publish`, однако по окончанию выполнения функции `_Publish`, я получаю ошибку:

```
loop.run_in_executor(func=await _Publish(data['newslettertext'], towhom=pressedINFO))
TypeError: run_in_executor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'executor'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Функцию `run_in_executor` можно передать 3 аргумента (исполнитель, функция, аргументы).

Аргумент `executor`(исполнитель) должен быть экземпляром `concurrent.futures.Executor`. Если исполнителем является `None`, то используется исполнитель по умолчанию.

Решение:

1. Попробуйте первым аргументом в функции передать `None`.
2. Попробуйте сделать функцию не асинхронной, а обычной (уберите `async`).

Comment: ```Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=TypeError("'NoneType' object is not callable")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable```

Comment: @MaximChyorny в той же строке ошибка?

Comment: да, я сделал то, что вы написали в ответе, в ответ от `asyncio`, я получаю ошибку о которой ранее написал.

Comment: @MaximChyorny Попробуйте вместо `get_event_loop` написать `get_running_loop`

Comment: `loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
            with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
                result = await loop.run_in_executor(
                    pool, await answermessages._send_newsletter_message(id_, text, keyboard))`

Comment: result = await loop.run_in_executor(
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Нужно было просто вызывать обычную функцию, а не асинхронную... из-за этого и были ошибки..

Comment: @MaximChyorny ясно, решение крылось в простом. Хорошо, что нашли. Тогда для правильности, давайте я скорректирую свой ответ на подходящий? Чтоб другим пользователям проще было.